# Define f(x) = (5x - 2) / (1 - 3x) with PolynomialFunction (or another class?) from org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.polynomials

Tags: java, math

I wrote this simple class and test for my training in using `PolynomialFunction` of `org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.polynomials`.

```java
public class Derivee {
   /**
    * Obtenir un nombre dérivé.
    * @param f Fonction.
    * @param x Valeur x0 où l'on veut le nombre dérivé.
    * @param h écart pour calculer la limite.
    * @return Nombre dérivé.
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException si h vaut zéro.
    */
   public double getNombreDerive(PolynomialFunction f, double x, double h) {
      Objects.requireNonNull(f, "La fonction ne peut pas valoir null");

      if (h == 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("L'écart pour calculer le nombre dérivé d'un polynôme ne peut pas valoir zéro.");
      }

      double nombreDerive = (f.value(x+h) - f.value(x)) / h;

      if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
         LOGGER.debug("Le nombre dérivé en {} est {} pour p(x) = {}, mesuré avec h = {}.", x, nombreDerive, f, h);
      }

      return nombreDerive;
   }
}
```

```java
class DeriveeTest {
   @Test @DisplayName("nombres dérivés")
   void nombresDerives() {
      PolynomialFunction f = new PolynomialFunction(new double[] {-2.0, 5.0});
      Derivee derivee = new Derivee();

      assertEquals(5.0, derivee.getNombreDerive(f, 3.0, 0.5), 0.01, "Le nombre dérivé n'est pas celui attendu");
      assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> derivee.getNombreDerive(f, 3.0, 0), "Un h = 0 a été accepté : il aurait dû être refusé");
   }
}
```

```
07:57:51.863 [main] DEBUG fr.ecoemploi.domain.utils.math.derivees.Derivee - 
   Le nombre dérivé en 3.0 est 5.0 pour p(x) = -2 + 5 x, mesuré avec h = 0.5.
```

It does work well. But how may I enter, for polynomial, the combination:
*f(x) = (5x - 2) / (1 - 3x)* ?

Comment: f(x) = (5x - 2) / (1 - 3x) is not a polynomial. You can use a polynomial to approximate it if you like.

Comment: Sweeper: No easy task to approximate this function with a polynomial near x = 1 /3.

Comment: This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why are you trying to use a `PolynomialFunction`? Why not simply `UnivariateFunction` or something like that? You don't seem to be using anything specific to `PolynomialFunction`s.

Comment: @Sweeper Maybe my title isn't perfect. What I'm willing to do is to enter an _u(x) / v(x)_ function (with u(x) = 5x -2, v(x) = 1 - 3x), whose derivative is u'.v - u.v' / v², etc. like we studied a lot at school.

Comment: What do you mean by "how may I enter it"? Don't use a `PolynomialFunction` and you can easily do `UnivariateFunction f = (x -> (5 * x - 2)/(1 - 3 * x));` Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(5x - 2) / (1 - 3x) is not a [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial), so you should not use `PolynomialFunction` here.

You can use the more general `UnivariantFunction` type to represent it. You can directly assign a lambda to it:

```
UnivariateFunction f = x -> (5 * x - 2)/(1 - 3 * x);
```

After replacing all the `PolynomialFunction`s in your code, you can pass `f` to `derivee.getNombreDerive` without compiler errors. You are not using anything exclusive to `PolynomialFunction`s.

Note that other than doing your own differentiation using `(f.value(x+h) - f.value(x)) / h`, you can also use `DerivativeStructure` from Apache.

You can make a `UnivariantDifferentiableFunction` like this:

```
var f = new UnivariateDifferentiableFunction() {
    @Override
    public double value(double x) {
        return (5 * x - 2)/(1 - 3 * x);
    }

    @Override
    public DerivativeStructure value(DerivativeStructure x) throws DimensionMismatchException {
        var numerator = x.multiply(5).subtract(2);
        var denominator = x.multiply(-3).add(1);
        return numerator.divide(denominator);
    }
};
```

And get the derivative at a certain point like this:

```
var point = 2; // suppose you want the derivative at x = 2.
var x = new DerivativeStructure(1, 1, 0, point);
System.out.println(f.value(x).getPartialDerivative(1));
```

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't have a clue about how succeeding to have the derivative number from a function with apache math3, I am just discovering, and you showed it to me. Thanks again!

Comment: How does it work if you have parameters of higher degrees? How do you write a `numerator` such as: `3x² + 5x -2`? `x.pow(2).multiply(3).add(x.multiply(5).substract(2))`?

Comment: @MarcLeBihan That seems correct. If you have further problems, consider posting a new question.